# ASP.NET MVC Input Model Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, data-binding

I want to bind the data from my View to my model attribute. I found several solutions but as i tried them, the Binding method in the Controller doesnt get triggered.

Model property(Events.cs):

`public string EventDay { get; set; }`

Input form:

```
    <div id="select-custom" class="box -custom">
        <label class="select-custom">
            <input class="input-custom" type="date" name="eventDay" value="dd-mm-yyyy" />
            <button type="submit" class="button-custom display-none">Search</button>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
     var eventDate = Request.Form["eventDay"];
     return View("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting an `id` on your input form element of `EventDay` and also match case with the name attribute and then on your controller action changing it to:

```
public ActionResult Search(Events body)
{
     var eventDate = body.EventDay;
     ...
}
```

You want your `Events` model class to be bound to from the request form values which ASP.NET should handle for you.

Comment: If i set an id in the form control, where should i reference it in the controller?

Comment: You don't need to reference it in the controller. ASP.NET model binding will take care of that if you give the input element an `id` that matches the property of the model your controller action accepts.

Comment: I set the `id` and the `name` to `EventDay` like its named in the model, but somehow the method wont get triggered with pressinig the submit button. I think there is the problem.